# Geocoding in R With "Tmaptools"

Tags: r

Does anyone know if this function can be used to geocode full addresses (e.g. 123 fake st, city, province, postal code) in R?

https://rdrr.io/cran/tmaptools/man/geocode_OSM.html

Or is this function only able to geocode as provide in the examples?

I am looking to take an example and return a longitude and latitude. Is it possible with this function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work

```r
library(tmaptools)
query <- geocode_OSM("250 Northern Ave, Boston, MA, 02210")
query
#$query
#[1] "250 Northern Ave, Boston, MA, 02210"
#
#$coords
#        x         y 
#-71.03812  42.34875 

#$bbox
#     xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#-71.03817  42.34870 -71.03807  42.34880 


# Test & visualise
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(query$coords[["x"]], query$coords[["y"]])
```

Longitude and latitude are given under `query$coords`.

[image]

Please also note the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) on the responsible use of OSM’s Nominatim geocoding service.

Comment: Wow, thank you! What a valuable resource!